# facebook graph api request fail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Hi I am using the facebook graph api in an android project and the project crashed today for no reason, after debugging the code I found that the request to the facebook graph api fail

here is my Kotlin code :

```
var graphRequest = GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/{${AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().userId}}/albums", null, HttpMethod.GET, object : GraphRequest.Callback {
                override fun onCompleted(response: GraphResponse?) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync()
```

I tried the request using the Graph API explorer to make sure that the code isn't the issue and it failed also:
[click to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjzyG.png)

I hope you can figure what is the real problem as I'm new to the api, thank you in advance.

Comment: When you see `{foo}` in the code examples in the documentation, it is meant as a placeholder - you are supposed to replace that with whatever the actual value of `foo` is, without the curly braces around it ...

Comment: thank you man you saved my day ... as I was stupidly convinced that it worked with the braces